# I am looking SOAP services which i want to do example by client

Tags: web-services, soap

I am just trying to understand how to query on SOAP services so are there any SOAP-based services which i can play with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a load of available SOAP web services here...
http://www.webservicex.net/WS/wscatlist.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are many SOAP based services available. You could write your own for testing.

Find More details here --> [SOAPClient](http://www.soapclient.com/websearch.html)

Example:

```
SOAP Endpoint URL:      http://www.SoapClient.com/xml/SQLDataSoap.WSDL
SOAP Action:    /SQLDataSRL
Method Names:   ProcessSRL
WSDL URL:   http://www.SoapClient.com/xml/SQLDataSoap.wsdl
Parameters:     

   1. SRLFile: The name of the Service Request Language File, use /xml/WEB.SRI for web searches.
   2. RequestName: The name of the search engine, use Altavista, Yahoo, Excite, etc.
   3. key: The keywords to be searched for.
```

Sample SOAP Message

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <mns:ProcessSRL xmlns:mns="http://www.SoapClient.com/xml/SQLDataSoap.xsd">
            <SRLFile xsi:type="xsd:string">/xml/web.sri</SRLFile>
            <RequestName xsi:type="xsd:string">Altavista</RequestName>
            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP</key>
        </mns:ProcessSRL>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```